# Aggregating spend by customer where accounts can be re-assigned to different customers

Tags: join, teradata

I want to join unique customer ids with their spends.

**Problem:** The account_no can be assigned to a different customer (A,B,C etc) at different point in time (assume an employee A leaving the organization and his account no is assigned to B).

**Eg from the tables below:** If a new customer, say B, is assigned an account number 123 (which was earlier assigned to A) on 1 Mar2015 then spend post 1 Mar2015 must fall in Bs remit til his account 123 is assigned to the next customer.

**Tables to Join:** Table 1 and Table 2

**Desired Result:** Table 3

Table 1: Assignment of account to different customers at different dates

```
Customer_ID   Account_no     Date 
A              123           1Feb2015   
B              123           1Mar2015
A              124           5Mar2015
C              123           1May2015
B              124           20May2015
```

Table 2: Daily level spend info

```
Account_no      Spend        Date
123             100         2Feb2015
123             200         2Mar2015
124             200         7Mar2015
123             200         17May2015
124             150         25May2015
```

Desired Output:

```
Customer_ID     Spend
A               100+200=300
B               150+200=350
C               200
```

The account No can be assigned twice, thrice or more to a different customer in case it is closed by multiple customers.

How do I aggregate the spend customer Id wise?

Comment: What queries have you tried so far?

Comment: MySQL or Teradata?

Comment: @dnoeth  teradata :)

Comment: @jcolebrand  For now I am extracting customer_ids which have similar account nos for a duration of interest, create a max and min date variable and then extract the spends. I know this is not an efficient way ,hence thought of posting it here!  Thanks.

Comment: And why the 150 should be associated with B and not A? Why the results shouldn't be (for example): A 850 (100+200+200+200+150), B 0, C 0?

Comment: @TypoCubeᵀᴹ The 150 should be associated with B because the account number 124 changed hand from A to B as determined by the Date column from Table 1. Hence any spend post 20th May gets assigned to B.

Comment: Then provide these details in the question. IDs that change hands sound like an uncommon (and awful) idea.

Comment: And provide the data in text (not image) and the rows in chronological order.

Comment: Yeah its uncommon but there are certain events wherein the same account is transferred to a with person with a new customer_id in corporate and organizational level.

Comment: Let me edit the question and replace the images.   Posted for the first time,please bear with me :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need a kind of *best-match* join like [@TypoCubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159179/66829)'s approach, but depending on the actual data (i.e. number of rows per Account_no) this might create a huge intermediate result before aggregation (and needs a uniqueness contraint on `table2(Account_no, Date)`).

The same logic logic can be achieved by a different approach using `UNION ALL` and `LAST_VALUE`:

```
SELECT Customer_ID, Sum(spend)
FROM 
 (
   SELECT
      -- assign the "previous" Customer_ID to the current row
      Last_Value(Customer_ID IGNORE NULLS) 
          -- within a date first rows from table1, followed by table2
      Over (ORDER BY Date, x) AS Customer_ID,
      Spend
   FROM
    (
      SELECT 
         1 AS x, -- flag indicating source table
         Customer_ID,
         Account_no,
         dt,
         -- need to cast to datatype of table2.Spend
         Cast(NULL AS ...) AS Spend
      FROM cust
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
         2 AS x,
         -- need to cast to datatype of table1.Customer_ID 
         Cast(NULL AS ...), 
         Account_no,
         dt,
         spend
      FROM spend
    ) AS dt
   QUALIFY -- only rows from table2
           x = 2
       AND -- only if table1 and table2 Account_no match
           Last_Value(CASE WHEN x = 1 THEN Account_no END IGNORE NULLS) 
           Over (ORDER BY dt, Spend) = Account_no

 ) AS dt
GROUP BY Customer_ID
;
```

Answer (score 0):

After the explanation that the accounts are changed / transfered to a different customer as shown in the `Customers_Accounts.date` column, so this table stores the starting date that an `account_no` is associated with a `customer_id`, we can try writing the query.

Assumptions:

- the first table is called `Customers_Accounts` and the second `Daily_Spend`.
- the logic or account transitions goes like:
  The row `B  123  1Mar2015` means that account 123 is reassigned to customer B on 2015-Mar-15, so it is no longer related to the previous customer (A) and stays assigned to B until it is reassigned to another customer (2015-May-01 to C).
- there is a `UNIQUE` constraint on `Customers_Accounts (account_no, date)` (otherwise a transition of an account from a customer to another would be ambiguous).
- there is a `UNIQUE` constraint on `Daily_Spend (account_no, date)`. This is not entirely needed. If there is different unique constraint on `Daily_Spend`, it should be used in the `PARTITION BY` clause instead.

Query:

```
WITH ct AS
  ( SELECT 
        ca.customer_id,
        ds.spend,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (PARTITION BY ds.account_no, ds.date     -- the PK of Daily_Spend
             ORDER BY ca.date DESC) 
            AS rn
    FROM
            Customers_Accounts AS ca
        JOIN 
            Daily_Spend AS ds
        ON 
            ca.account_no = ds.account_no
        AND ca.date <= ds.date
  )
SELECT
    customer_id,
    SUM(spend) AS spend
FROM
    ct
WHERE
    rn = 1
GROUP BY
    customer_id ;
```

Tested in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/52fc1/1) (in Postgres as no Teradata available).